# VS 2017 - Rebuild until it works?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I open a new project (usually, it's branched from TFS) and sync it locally, the first build never succeeds... i have to keep pressing rebuild, until it works... I assume this is some kind of bug related to my solution, because other smaller solutions work fine.

Details:

- It's always complaining about missing DLL's
- There's no exact number of rebuilds, it's around 3 or 4, but i just "fixed" a project doing about 10...
- Using VS 2017 enterprise, fully updated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have your dependencies specified properly in your solution.  When your build fails look to see what project it is that fails and what project it couldn't find.  Then add the dependency.

Comment: they are correctly specified. I know that because, as stated on the question, it's only a matter of how many times i have to press "Rebuild Solution" without changing anything